# How to debug programs that load from another one? with radare2/gdb

Tags: debugging, radare2, gdb, debuggers

I'm reversing engendering a plugin. This plugin is loaded into memory by the main program. 
I disassemble the plugin with radare2 but I don't know how to debug it.
I try with gdb but same problem.

I know is possible because I have done it in Hopper but I don't know to to do it with radare2 or gdb.

one of the obstacles is, I load the plugin with radare2 to disassembler it but I can't put any breakpoint because is not set it in debug mode. Also, I can't set the debug mode because the plugin can't start by it self. Maybe I need I command that will start my main program before the debug? is there anything like that in radare2? I was reading about rarun2 but I can't make it work for something like this

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: how does the additional code loaded and/or executed? What about putting a breakpoint there and follow the execution?

Comment: Let's say is a Firefox plugin... I don't know where to put a breakpoint in Firefox. With Hopper I would open the plugin set the breakpoints (to the plugin) then in the debugger options instead of execute the plugin a execute Firefox then the program stop when gets to the plugin breakpoint

Comment: @PawełŁukasik any other info i can give you. Looks like you know a lot about radare2. I would appreciated a lot

Comment: it would be great if you would have a specific example (code) for someone (not only me) to try and see the issue and propose a solution. I don't have that much time and preparing something from scratch and then seeing that it might not be exactly what you wanted is a potential stopper for me.